# Visual Studio Designer and Control Derived from ComboBox

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I'm trying to keep Visual Studio from attempting to serialize the `datasource` of drop down list. It's just a simple control that loads its datasource from the database, and inherits from ComboBox. My objects I use for the datasoure are not serializable so it errors when I trying to do almost anything the designer, saying code generation has failed. I've tried adding this to my code hoping that it would stop VS from doing this but it hasn't worked.

```
    <Obsolete("This property does nothing.")>
    <System.ComponentModel.Browsable(False)> _
    <System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)> _
    Public Shadows Property Datasource() As Object
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)

        End Set
    End Property
```

It still somehow is accessing `datasource`, so it must be seeing my control as a `ComboBox` and reading the base class property. Is there anything I can do to stop it?

Comment: How are you loading the datasource from the database?  Sounds like the designer is trying to do that, too.  The problem is not in the posted code.

Comment: @LarsTech, The problem is not in the posted code, its in the VS designer (no code available). I load my datasource in the constructor, for some reason VS is trying very hard to serialize the datasource that I loaded and then put it in the `InitializeComponent` function.

Comment: The designer does have to run the empty constructor.  Does `If Not Me.DesignMode Then` work if you put it front of your DataSource setting?

Comment: Such are the hazards of the *Shadows* keyword.  It merely *adds* a new property, it doesn't replace the existing one.  You cannot un-inherit a property, this can only work when the original one is virtual (Overridable in vb.net).  DataSource is not virtual.  A TypeDescriptor could solve the problem, you gotta really care to tackle that.

Comment: `.DesignMode` didn't work but i found a method with `System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager` that works so that i don't fill the datasource during design time, so it has nothing to serialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what I was thinking, but I guess it does answer the question, as I am OK with the control not being bound to a datasource during design time, but using this property,

```
if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
{
    // design time only stuff
}
else
{
    // runtime only stuff.
}
```

From this article: http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/01/identifying-run-time-and-design-mode.html

I can prevent myself from loading the datasource during design time, so VS has nothing to attempt to serialize.